# C# 4.0 Dynamic vs Expando... where do they fit?

Tags: c#-4.0, expandoobject, dynamicobject, dynamic-keyword

I am trying to learn all the new goodies that come with C# 4.0. I am failing to understand the differences between the `DynamicObject` and `ExpandoObject` types. It seems like `DynamicObject` is used e.g. when you want to access variables from Python scripts and `ExpandoObject` when talking with COM/Office objects. Am I right? What is the difference in their use?

Comment: Better answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565481/differences-between-expandoobject-dynamicobject-and-dynamic

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Expando *is a* `dynamic` type to which members can be added (or removed) at runtime. `dynamic` is designed to allow .NET to interoperate with types when interfacing with dynamic typing languages such as Python and JavaScript.

So, if you need to handle a dynamic type: use `dynamic` and if you need to handle dynamic data such as XML or JSON: use ExpandoObject

The declaration of an expando shows the relationship between dynamic and the expando:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
```

And the ability to add a new property:

```
expando.SomeNewStringVal = "Hello World!";
```

That last line of code creates a brand new string property in the expando object called `SomeNewStringVal`. The string type is inferred from the assignment.

So an expando is a dynamic data type that can represent dynamically changing data. That's it in a nutshell. [Here's a deeper look at dynamic and expando](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx).

**Complete example:**

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
        expando.SomeNewStringVal = "Hello Brave New Whirrled!";
        Console.WriteLine(expando.SomeNewStringVal);

        // more expando coolness/weirdness:
        var p = expando as IDictionary<String, object>;
        p["A"] = "New val 1";
        p["B"] = "New val 2";

        Console.WriteLine(expando.A);
        Console.WriteLine(expando.B);
    }
}
```

Comment: Though he has accepted it, I think the OP meant difference between DynamicObject and ExpandoObject.

Comment: Just to note this does come in handy at time in the real world. I just used it out API to create dyanmic response objects before serializing to xml or json. This way I can recursively add sub classes with distinct property names without having to define a ton of explicit properties. "GroupsL1": [{ "GroupingL2:: [{...

Comment: [`DynamicObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=netframework-4.7) was left unaddressed. MSDN: *Provides a base class for specifying dynamic behavior at run time. This class must be inherited from; you cannot instantiate it directly.* The MSDN page contains a simplified `ExpandoObject` implementation based on `DynamicObject`. So, both the types are used with late binding, but `ExpandoObject` is concrete (and sealed), while `DynamicObject` is just a base class for custom dynamic objects.