# When/Why should I use late-binding? (DynamicObject and ExpandoObject)

Tags: c#, dynamic, late-binding, expandoobject, dynamicobject

While `DynamicObjects` and `ExpandoObjects` ([Differences between ExpandoObject, DynamicObject and dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565481/differences-between-expandoobject-dynamicobject-and-dynamic)) sound quite useful at first, i did never actually use them. It feels like late-binding is quite unsafe/unstable since it might throw errors at run-time which could've otherwise been avoided. In general MSDN points out several advantages of early-binding and suggests not to use late-binding at all if possible (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx).

Since I was never in a situation that i could not solve without late-binding and since it seems to be considered 'bad style', I would like to know if there are there situations that actually require the use of late-binding. Do you have any examples where you used late-binding (in particular the DynamicObject or ExpandoObject) and had a good reason for this design choice exept for it being "easy to code"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the times it's better to stay away from using `dynamic` and adhere to
a type-safe programming style.

But *there are* situations when using `dynamic` could make your life better, or even more, could allow you to do really cool stuff that would be impossible to do without `dynamic`.

### ExpandoObject

Consider the following example (without using `ExpandoObject`):

```
Dictionary<String, object> info = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<String, object> person = new Dictionary<string,object>();
info["Person"] = person;
person["Name"] = "John";
person["Surname"] = "Smith";
```

Now using `ExpandoObject`:

```
dynamic info = new ExpandoObject();
info.Person = new ExpandoObject();
info.Person.Name = "John";
info.Person.Surname = "Smith";
```

Isn't this better? You could use `ExpandoObject` instead of dictionary whenever you need some kind of *property bag* to manipulate big hierarchies of objects. But if you have a plain small dictionary, probably, it's better to stick to the dictionary - it's clearer and there is no performance overhead.

### DynamicObject

Now imagine that you have huge hierarchy of objects (say, coming from JSON). 
You could create custom `DynamicObject` to deserialize JSON into dynamic object easily, see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object).
You can do a lot of more cool things via `DynamicObject`!

---

Plus, DLR (and dynamic support in C#) allows you, for example, to execute dynamic languages (e.g.IronRuby) from C# context.

As you see, dynamic support in C# is a very powerful concept, but must be used only whenever appropriate.