# Dynamic for unknown type, how else could be this implemented?

Tags: c#, database, generics, dynamic, parameters

I have some classes (entities) that represent database tables

```
public class ALBUM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Tracks { get; set; }
}
public class BOOK
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get, set; }
}
```

Then to get parameters to respective stored procedures, insert, update, any

```
public Command getParameters(string spName, dynamic entity, Connection conn)
{
   Command cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.CommandText = spName;

   // Get properties (fields) from entity (table)
   PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();

   for (int = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
   {
       // here I set Parameters: name, DBType, and Value from properties
   }
}
```

Now I call

```
public void Some()
{
   ALBUM someAlbum = new ALBUM();
   BOOK anyBook = new BOOK();      // all respective data from DB is set

   Command newCommand = getParameters("myAlbumSP", someAlbum, myConnection);
   Command newCommand = getParameters("mySPBooks", anyBook, myConnection);
}
```

How else colud I define "entity" parameter?, not to be dynamic.
It works, just I'm lookin for some other way to do it, I´m sure there is plenty of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `entity` does not *need* to be `dynamic` (although it is certainly OK). Using `object` instead would be sufficient, because you do not call anything outside of what `object` gives you. This works, because you use *reflection*. With `dynamic`, on the other hand, you could specify properties not found on `object`, and the compiler would not complain.

For example, since both `ALBUM` and `BOOK` have an `Id` parameter, you could write something like this:

```
var entityId = entity.Id;
```

This would work as long as `entity` is `dynamic`; it would not work with an `object`.

Comment: I see, and is there any difference between them (object - dynamic) talking about memory resources, or speed?

Comment: +1. @Eduardo, comparing `object` and `dynamic` on speed is very hard in general because you can't do `objectMy.Id` unlike `dynamicMy.Id`. In your particular case since your code uses zero functionality from `dynamic` there is unlikely to be measurable difference (try yourself - potentially dynamic would be a bit slower). Also require caller to pass more complex type (`dynamic` vs. `object`) for no good reason is not sign of good code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *ExpandoObject* class. As Paul Sasik said:

> Expando is a dynamic type designed to handle dynamic data by
>   adding/removing members at runtime. dynamic is designed to allow .NET
>   to interoperate with types when interfacing with dynamic typing
>   languages such as Python and JavaScript.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540291/322848

Here is an article that explains the *ExpandoObject*:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx