# Convert class to dynamic and add properties

Tags: c#

I have a class `MyClass`. I would like to convert this to a dynamic object so I can add a property.

This is what I had hoped for:

```
dynamic dto = Factory.Create(id);
dto.newProperty = "123";
```

I get the error:

```
WEB.Models.MyClass does not contain a definition for 'newProperty'
```

Is that not possible?

Comment: dynamic does not mean you can add properties on the go. It means you don't know what it will be so you use dynamic (as far as I know) and the type will be figured out at runtime.

Comment: You need to use [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to add properties. Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540161/c-sharp-4-0-dynamic-vs-expando-where-do-they-fit) with some info that might help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following has worked for me in the past:

It allows you to convert any object to an Expando object.

```
public static dynamic ToDynamic<T>(this T obj)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        var currentValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
        expando.Add(propertyInfo.Name, currentValue);
    }
    return expando as ExpandoObject;
}
```

Based on: http://geekswithblogs.net/Nettuce/archive/2012/06/02/convert-dynamic-to-type-and-convert-type-to-dynamic.aspx

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I get an error: Expression of type 'System.Guid' cannot be used for return type 'System.String'

Comment: What advantage does the expression tree have over `expando.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(obj));`? And why does it convert property names to lowercase? And why does it cast an `ExpandoObject` to `ExpandoObject` when returning?

Comment: @chris I used it for a specific case. For this post, it is indeed not required. Please see updated answer.

Comment: @Sean, I'm pretty sure that error came from treating all properties as being strings when it formed the `Lambda<Func<string>>` instead of using the actual type of the property as the return type. I'm not sure how one would actually do that properly.

Answer (score 4):

As my object has JSON specific naming, I came up with this as an alternative:

```
public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object obj)
{
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(ExpandoObject));
}
```

For me the results worked great:

Model:

```
public partial class Settings
{
  [JsonProperty("id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("runTime")]
  public TimeSpan RunTime { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("retryInterval")]
  public TimeSpan RetryInterval { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("retryCutoffTime")]
  public TimeSpan RetryCutoffTime { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("cjisUrl")]
  public string CjisUrl { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("cjisUserName")]
  public string CjisUserName { get; set; }

  [JsonIgnore]
  public string CjisPassword { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("importDirectory")]
  public string ImportDirectory { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("exportDirectory")]
  public string ExportDirectory { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("exportFilename")]
  public string ExportFilename { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("jMShareDirectory")]
  public string JMShareDirectory { get; set; }

  [JsonIgnore]
  public string Database { get; set; }
}
```

I used it in this manner:

```
private static dynamic DynamicSettings(Settings settings)
{
  var settingsDyn = settings.ToDynamic();
  if (settingsDyn == null)
    return settings;
  settingsDyn.guid = Guid.NewGuid();
  return settingsDyn;
}
```

And received this as a result:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "runTime": "07:00:00",
  "retryInterval": "00:05:00",
  "retryCutoffTime": "09:00:00",
  "cjisUrl": "xxxxxx",
  "cjisUserName": "xxxxx",
  "importDirectory": "import",
  "exportDirectory": "output",
  "exportFilename": "xxxx.xml",
  "jMShareDirectory": "xxxxxxxx",
  "guid": "210d936e-4b93-43dc-9866-4bbad4abd7e7"
}
```

I don't know about speed, I mean it is serializing and deserializing, but for my use it has been great. A lot of flexability like hiding properties with JsonIgnore.

Note: xxxxx above is redaction. :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add members to class instances on the fly.

But you can use [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Use factory to create new one and initialize it with properties which you have in `MyClass`:

```
public static ExpandoObject Create(int id)
{
    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
    obj.Id = id;
    obj.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    // etc
    return obj;
}
```

Then you can add new members:

```
dynamic dto = Factory.Create(id);
dto.newProperty = "123";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add properties to types at runtime. However, there is an exception which is: [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx). So if you need to add properties at runtime you should use `ExpandoObject`, other types don't support this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add up my experience, if you are using JSON.NET, then below might be one of the solution:

```
var obj....//let obj any object
ExpandoObject expandoObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```

Not tested performances etc.. but works.