# A way to combine 2 unrelated JSON objects

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization

Suppose I have 2 objects:

```
public class CInfo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string cID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string cName { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Time")]
    public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Note")]
    public string comment { get; set; } 
}
```

Couple of functions return the following:

```
CInfo cInfo = getCInfo();
List<Event> = getEvents();
```

Both of these meant to be combined together, into a final (hypothetical) object that needs to look this:

```
public class CInfoWithEvents
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string cID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string cName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Events")]
    public List<Event> { get; set; }
}
```

At which point the intention is to do a `JsonConvert.SerialzeObject(CInfoWithEvents)`, and get a json string representing this final object.

Question:  what is the best way to combine them? There has to be a more elegant way than just creating whole new object and copying each property, or worse:  serialize `cInfo` and `List<Event>` separately and do some sort of string manipulation.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Include the entire `CInfo` as a single property? `class CInfoWithEvents { public CInfo CInfo {get;set;}; public List<Event> {get;set;}}` Or do something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/42836936/11683?

Comment: @GSerg I appreciate the response, but Im not sure were talking about the same thing: final object is basically a `CInfo` with `List<Event>` property added.  I considered creating a derived class `class CInfoWithEvents:cInfo { [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Events")]  public List<Event> { get; set; }}` but i'd be back to just copying properties one by one if I wanted to populate this new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement this in various ways besides copying each property of both classes:

1) Add both class as public property in the third class.

```
public class CInfoWithEvents
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CInfo")]
    public CInfo  {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Events")]
    public List<Event> { get; set; }
}
```

2) Inherit from CInfo class and have a List as public property.

```
public class CInfoWithEvents : CInfo
{        
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Events")]
    public List<Event> { get; set; }
}
```

3) Create on the fly:

```
  var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  var resultJson =  javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(new { CInfo = getCInfo(), Events = getEvents()});
```

4) Using JObject

```
    JObject jCInfo = JObject.FromObject(getCInfo());
    jCInfo.Add("Events", JArray.FromObject(getEvents()));
    string json = jCInfo.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your response.  1 and 3 produce the same result and both result in a structure that is different from what I am looking for:  they are not equivalent to `CInfoWithEvents` object.  #2 would result in a correct structure, but in order to populate this derived object I would need to assign each property individually, which i want to avoid for the purposes of future maintenance.

Comment: please check #4

Comment: this is it!  thank you kindly!!  one small correction to this specific example is that it shoudl be `jCInfo.Add("Events", JArray.FromObject(getEvents()));', otherwise #4 is the solution

Comment: Welcome, Edited my answer now. Enjoy Coding! !!